# insert exec opendatasource error 7391

Tags: sql, servidor

Buen dia,

Ejecuto este codigo en una base de datos sql server 2008 R2, dominio DBDS1 a otra base de datos sql server 2012 dominio coms1 y me arroja una tabla con los datos correctamente.

```
EXEC OPENDATASOURCE ('SQLOLEDB','Password=6tgfjsoeuW.;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=usr_test;Initial Catalog=BDDEV;Data Source=10.163.37.131')
.DOCBASE3.dbo.Sp_ReporteCumplimiento 
        4,
        '',
        '',
        @FechaInicial,
        @FechaFinal,
        '8600343137',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        ''
```

El problema es que cuando antes del EXEC coloco la sentencia insert into @tablaTemporal me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned
>   message "No transaction is active.". Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2,
>   Procedure Sp_ReporteCumplimiento, Line 96 The operation could not be
>   performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server
>   "(null)" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

Pero si hago el mismo proceso: un insert a una tabla temporal, de una tabla en lugar de un stored procedure, no genera error, hace el insert correctamente y luego hago select a mi tabla temporal y todo esta perfecto. Solo sale error cuando combino insert del resultado de un exec que apunta a un stored procedure.

Los dos servidores estan en dominios diferentes, ambos tienen configurado DTC. Funciona consultas a las tablas, funciona insert a tabla temporal de tabla remota, pero insert del sp no funciona.
Que puede ser ?

Answer (score -1):

¿Tienes Vinculados los servidores? si no es así podrías intentar vinculando los servidores y ejecutar el insert parecido a esto

```
Insert into Tabla
EXEC [10.163.37.131].DOCBASE3.dbo.Sp_ReporteCumplimiento 
        4,
        '',
        '',
        @FechaInicial,
        @FechaFinal,
        '8600343137',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        ''
```

Comment: Hola, si los tengo vinculados y me sucede exactamente lo mismo. El insert de una tabla me funciona perfecto, pero el del SP saca ese error. Te comento tambien, mi SQL Origen es 2008r2 el otro es 2012. El servidor que tiene alojado SQL server 2008 tiene windows server 2008 y el que tiene alojado SQL server 2012 es windows server 2012 r2. El puente va del 2008 al 2012.